# Multithreading using functions in the windows.h library

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm thinking about using the windows.h library for multithreading. I was exploring the web for some examples, but the only one I got [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was very complex. Are there any simple examples that I can see?

If you use Qt, using the QThread library is a good way to multithread.

Comment: Welcome to the world of C APIs. It sure is complex.

Comment: Multithreading in Windows is complicated. Multithreading in general is complicated when you consider the number of things you have to think about for thread safety. That example looks pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: An example that's at least 100 lines.. come on.. should I use QThread then?

Comment: Haha, coroutines in Lua were extremely simple. I'm not sure whether multithreading and coroutines are the same though..

Comment: The sample is extremely verbose. This is typical for msdn samples. Dont know why. Copy paste the code, delete all the comments, cut away the paranoid error handling, then you can see whats going on.

Comment: An example (your code won't create a loop to create multiple threads) of 100 lines with error checking, comments and **plain C syntax**? You can't get something more simple whatever you may use!!! (Write same code with QThread, **it's not shorter** if you do the same things)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using VC++? If so what version of it? The VC++11 Beta adds std::thread. Since VC++10 there has been the PPL (Parallel Patterns Library). The CRT also has some threading functions (_beginthread etc).

Comment: Qt Creator? Then you're using mingw. How about QThread then?

Comment: I looked that up, but it seemed to be lacking examples. Could I see any simple ones? Also, I was thinking of Boost, but I've never used any of their libraries before.

Answer (score 0):

Threading ain't simple.

However, take a look at my [hodge podge program](https://bitbucket.org/alfps/ahodgepodgewinapiandopencvprogram), which combines a bit of this and a little of that.

It just presents video from a cam in an API level window, using API threading and OpenCV.